# Toast bread slices in a convection microwave?

Tags: bread, microwave

Does a **convection microwave** make decent toast, as a toaster oven would or a bone fide oven set to broil?  I have read far and wide on the internet and in operating manuals for Sharp, Bosch, etc. convection microwaves and have come up empty handed.  I know you can't make toast in a microwave, but these are ***convection*** microwaves we're talking about here.

Would prefer to hear from someone who actually owns one of these things instead of someone just reading things like "CompuBroil®, CompuRoast®, CompuBake® - automatically compute broiling, roasting, and baking times/temperature settings." from the [www.sharpusa.com](http://www.sharpusa.com/ForHome/HomeAppliances/MicrowaveOvens/R1874.aspx) website like me :-)

Additional specific requirements for our situation are an "Over The Range" (OTR) solution, for which there are often microwave and convection microwave solutions that include 300CFM ventilation and lighting for our cooktop.  We're not looking for a countertop unit.  Hence the desire to see if these convection microwave units can do the deed!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specifically looking for someone who has a CM and has (or has not) successfully made quality toasted bread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a old post.. But I just made toast in my microwave/convection combo and its' good.. I defrosted my bread in the microwave, the put it on a the metal rack for 10 minutes at 425. It worked !!! I know it's 10 minutes but it allowed me to cook the eggs etc...

Comment: whats the make/model of your microwave?

Comment: Now this is exactly what I was looking for -- real life experience toasting bread in a convection microwave.

Answer (score 13):

Toasting bread involves the [Maillard Reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction) and requires a dry heat.  Toasters and toaster ovens (and conventional ovens) use radiant heat.  Convection ovens use convection, as the name implies, and this is most certainly a dry and very even heat; the question is whether or not a convection microwave actually provides a true convective environment, like a high-end convection oven.

And that's where the problem generally lies.  Convection microwaves (AKA microwave convection ovens) are not usually true convection ovens.  They use a combination of microwaves *and* convection currents, which will quickly cause steaming and inhibit the Maillard reaction.  This isn't really a problem with, say, chicken, but it's a big problem with bread.  You'll have many of the same problems you'd have with a regular microwave - the bread will burn before it toasts.

What you really want is a [microwave toaster oven](http://www.nextag.com/microwave-toaster/stores-html).  They exist, and are often very cheap.  If it doesn't actually bill itself as being a combination microwave/toaster oven, then it's not going to be very good at toasting.

Comment: Thank you for the background and theoretical underpinnings of toasting bread.  Some of these models advertise specific and dedicated broil, bake, etc. methods -- leading me to believe that they are legitimate little ovens in the own right without MW power added.  I still need to know if a Convection Microwave can or cannot toast bread.

Comment: @Mark: A convection microwave cannot *ipso facto* toast bread.  That is why microwave/toaster ovens exist.  If you want to know whether or not a *specific* convection microwave might be different from the others then you'll need to be more specific with your question - or better yet, contact the manufacturer.  But in general, unless you specifically see a line in there advertising an ability to toast, then it can't toast.

Comment: @Aaronut: convection microwaves typically advertise many different modes: Microwave, Microwave/Convection and Convection as separately available exclusive modes.

Comment: @Mark: If that is the case and you are certain that the convection mode is true convection (exposed heating elements are a bad sign), then yes, it will toast.  However, it will do so rather slowly and inefficiently.  If you are not going to get a microwave toaster oven (for which there are several range models that also do convection) then you are honestly better off buying a $20 toaster for your toast.

Comment: One exception I can think of is if the unit has a broiler or grill; that would be fairly effective at toasting bread.

Answer (score 1):

Sharp used to make a convection microwave toaster oven with a turntable and heating elements above. Made toast,  no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It does toast! I just tried it. Followed the above instructions set it to 425. Not sure how it really worked I just watched it and when it looked toasted took it out.

Comment: 425 what? ºF? Minutes? CFM?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is "yes, you can very well toast bread in a convection microwave".
Just follow the following steps:

- Step 1: preheat the oven to 200 C.
- Step 2: you would need convection + grill combination to toast your bread. In case you don't have it by default, most of the microwaves use convection + grill to preheat itself.
  Put your bread on a steel tripod stand and use convection + grill for 2-3 min or until brown.
- Step 3: flip over and cook the other side for 2-3 min or until brown.
- Step 4: voila you can now enjoy your bread cooked better than a toaster.